# migrating existing chat database to XMPP (jabber) db

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe

I have an existing chat and profile website with 250k of active users. The users have profiles and so on. Currently, I made the chat myself with ajax, but I'm moving on to the XMPP protocol.

For this I installed Openfire and got it working with a js client framework strophejs, I made a simple test client and all works fine.

What I don't know is how to, for example, add a picture or a profile to an openfire user. When I get a 'presence' update from the server I only get the username/email. I want to extend the user with a profile from my own db, or migrate my exisitng db to openfire's db, but then where do I put the profile data?

Could anyone give me some pointers here?

Thanks,

Elger

Answer (score 0):

just use the vCard for storing profile information and the picture (XEP-0054) http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html . Further information you can find in this book (Chapter 4): http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596521271.do .